# Disable auto login - facebook javascript SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to disable auto login in my website when there is a facebook session user. I want the user to click on the facebook login button

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want the user to click login? Does this make more information about the user available to you, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of facebook events, simply use **FB.Login**.

Call the userLogin(), when the user click your Login button (not the facebook login button, but a simple button)

```
function userLogin()
    {
        FB.login(function(response) 
        {
           if (response.authResponse) 
           {
             console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
             location.href = "REDIRECT_TO.php";
           } 
           else 
           {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
           }
         });
    }
```

So now, the user have to click on the facebook login button every time he visits your site.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this.

```
FB.init({
    appId      : 'key',
    status     : false,
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                              // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
});
```

and auto login will be disabled.
just put status on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Add "status: false" inside your FB.init.

This will prevent an existing Facebook session from logging users in automatically.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Init

Comment: This does not work. Parsing xfbml automatically logs in anyways unlike the documentation claims.